# How to check if an element's color is equal to its background color (after rendering) in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, colors, background-color

What is the easiest way to check for elements hidden by identical color/background-color in pure JavaScript?

Example: White text on white background in a div. I want to check the rendered color/background color for the element, so it works even with external CSS styles applied.

Also, no jQuery available so it has to be done in pure JavaScript.

Comment: What if the background is transparent? What if it is an image? What if it has absolutely positioned content under it? This is actually a rather complicated problem to solve.

Comment: I know it is complicated - that's why I am asking - perhaps somebody already has had this problem before. Actually I want to check for the rendered/displayed background, so if the background of the div in my example is transparent, it perhaps would be the background of a parent div or the body for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Get target coordinates, then find next top-most element from that point

1. You could use [`element.getClientBoundingRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the top and left offset positions of the target element. Then use [`window.getComputedStyle(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get its computed color.
2. Temporarily remove the target element as the topmost element. In my example, I do this by changing the z-index of the target element so that it falls below the others in the stacking context. There are other ways.
3. Then use [`document.elementFromPoint(left, top)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) to get the next top-most element at that position. Then use [`window.getComputedStyle(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get its computed background-color for comparison.
4. Restore the target element to its top-most position.

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

myButton.onclick = findHiddenText;

function findHiddenText() {
    var textElem = document.getElementById('myText'),
        textOffset = textElem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        textColor = getStyle(textElem, 'color'),
        textZindex = getStyle(textElem, 'zIndex');
    
    textElem.style.zIndex = '-1'; 
    
    var bgElem = document.elementFromPoint(textOffset.left, textOffset.top),
        bgColor = getStyle(bgElem, 'backgroundColor');
    
    if (textColor === bgColor) {
        var msgElem = document.createElement('p'),
            msgText = document.createTextNode('There be hidden treasure in the sea.');
        msgElem.appendChild(msgText);
        document.getElementById('box2').appendChild(msgElem);
        textElem.style.textShadow = '0 1px 1px #000';
    };
    textElem.style.zIndex = textZindex;
}

function getStyle(elem, prop) {
    if (elem.currentStyle) {
        return elem.currentStyle[prop];
    }
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null)[prop]; 
}
```

```css
#box1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}
#box2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: sandybrown;
}
#myText {
    color: lightseagreen;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2">
    <p id="myText">Treasure.</p>
</div>
<button id="myButton" type="button">Find buried treasure</button>
```

*NOTE: This would not work if the returned element's background-color is transparent. In that case, I imagine you could write a function to check for transparency, then temporarily remove transparent elements from the DOM or change their stacking order and repeat the process with `.elementFromPoint()` until you find an element with a defined background-color. After doing your comparison, you could restore removed/moved elements.*

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. Regarding your jsfiddle: You check the text background-color instead of the color?! Also: $(bgElem).css('background-color') is rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) in your example, not lightseagreen - because it finds the transparent p-element like you described.

Comment: You're right. Also, the elementFromPosition is returning the P tag (it is top most), hence why the two values matched even though I grabbed background color. I'll work on it. I think this is the right direction though.

Comment: @tholu I have updated my response and jsfiddle to get the computed style before comparison. You'll also see that the z-index of the text element temporarily gets moved so that it is not the topmost element anymore. It is restored at the end of the function.